# Call .apk to run in my app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, methods, executable

I have an AIR application on Android (make in AS3), how can I call a. Apk on my sdcard to run automatically without the user having to go to the folder and click the executable? (this would be a process version upgrade ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you could run an .apk via your app.
[But AIR has a built in feature for updating an app](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7c57.html)

Comment: That update method is solely for desktop AIR. It cannot be used for mobile apps (unless it is undocumented/underdocumented and I never noticed that it was possible for Android. Definitely not possible for iOS if you want to be in the App Store)

Comment: I've imagined ... I decided the other way, I appreciate the help!